# form POST + direct. Not posting

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect

ok so here is my HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<!-- XHTML ADVANCED -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Find Hotels</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   a:visted {color:#e27023; }
    .duksai {margin-right:10px; font-size:12pt; margin-left:58px; font-family:arial; }
    .ifivmjg {margin-right:10px; font-size:14pt; margin-left:20px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; }
    body {color:#000; width:640px; font-family:arial; margin:0 auto; }
    .ijvdpgk {padding-top:10px; }
    .dropDownValuesText1 {font-size:12pt; margin-left:10px; font-family:arial; }
    .marginLeftRight10px {margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; }
    a:link {color:#d74119; }
    .famvote {margin-right:10px; padding-top:5px; text-align:right; font-size:11pt; margin-left:10px; font-family:arial; }
    .headerRightButton {text-align:right; margin:5px; }
    .ngcwmjg {margin-right:10px; font-size:14pt; margin-left:25px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; }
    .header {height:45px; width:640px; background-color:white; }
    a:active {color:#ffe2b0; }
    .onhqbwf {color:#8E8077; text-align:center; width:640px; font-size:10px; font-family:arial; }
    .umoanjg {margin-right:10px; font-size:14pt; margin-left:10px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; }
    .pgrvmh {margin-right:10px; font-size:12pt; margin-left:28px; font-family:arial; }
    .fwmduhg {display:none; }
    .luadegf {height:34px; width:249px; margin-left:40px; border:0; }
    .etqkskk {border-top-style:solid; padding-top:3px; height:24px; text-align:center; font-size:12px; background-color:#EFEFEF; border-color:#CDC5C0; font-family:arial; border-width:1px; padding-bottom:3px; }
    .vbjanh {margin-right:10px; font-size:12pt; margin-left:10px; font-family:arial; }
    .hhsrkom {width:640px; }
    .Label {font-size:14pt; margin-left:10px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; }
    .lghspdf {text-align:right; width:65%; }
    img {border:0; }
    .oaoftwj {margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    a:hover {color:#ffe2b0; }
    .gwlmmic {text-align:center; width:320px; }

  </style><meta   name="description"  content="Find Hotels"/>

 </head>
 <body class="oaoftwj">

  <table class="header">
   <tr>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="lghspdf">
    <img  src="http://prodcache.internal.ihg.com/content/dam/mobile/6c/en/us/intercontinental-hotels-group.jpg" alt="Brand Logo" width="76" height="45"/>
    </td>
    <td class="headerRightButton">

    <a href="http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/6c/us/en/home.action"><img  src="http://prodcache.internal.ihg.com/content/dam/mobile/6c/en/us/btn_med_return-to-search.gif" alt="Home" width="70" height="17"/></a>
    </td>

   </tr>

  </table>
  <!-- TextBlock -->
  <div class="etqkskk">
   For Reservations:<a  href="tel:+448000839876" >

         44 800 083 9876</a><br />

  </div>

  <!-- TextBlock -->
  <div class="ijvdpgk">

  </div>

  <!-- TextBlock -->
  <div class="famvote">

   * Indicates required field 
  </div>

  <form  action="functions.php" method="post">
   <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="GBR">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="SWINDON" /><br />
    <span class="umoanjg">Check-In Date&#160;*</span><br />
    <select  class="vbjanh" name="checkinDay" title="">
      <option  value="1" >1</option>
       <option  value="2" >2</option>

       <option  value="3" >3</option>
       <option  value="4" >4</option>
       <option  value="5" >5</option>
       <option  value="6" >6</option>
       <option  value="7" >7</option>
       <option  value="8" >8</option>

       <option  value="9" >9</option>
       <option  value="10" >10</option>
       <option  value="11" >11</option>
       <option  value="12" >12</option>
       <option  value="13" >13</option>
       <option  value="14" >14</option>

       <option  value="15" >15</option>
       <option  value="16" >16</option>
       <option  value="17"  selected="selected">17</option>
       <option  value="18" >18</option>
       <option  value="19" >19</option>
       <option  value="20" >20</option>

       <option  value="21" >21</option>
       <option  value="22" >22</option>
       <option  value="23" >23</option>
       <option  value="24" >24</option>
       <option  value="25" >25</option>
       <option  value="26" >26</option>

       <option  value="27" >27</option>
       <option  value="28" >28</option>
       <option  value="29" >29</option>
       <option  value="30" >30</option>
       <option  value="31" >31</option>

     </select>

     <select  class="vbjanh" name="checkinMonthYear" title="">
      <option  value="092010"  selected="selected">October 2010</option>
       <option  value="102010" >November 2010</option>
       <option  value="112010" >December 2010</option>
       <option  value="002011" >January 2011</option>
       <option  value="012011" >February 2011</option>

       <option  value="022011" >March 2011</option>
       <option  value="032011" >April 2011</option>
       <option  value="042011" >May 2011</option>
       <option  value="052011" >June 2011</option>
       <option  value="062011" >July 2011</option>
       <option  value="072011" >August 2011</option>

       <option  value="082011" >September 2011</option>

     </select>
     <br />
    <br />
    <span class="umoanjg">Check-Out Date&#160;*</span><br />
    <select  class="vbjanh" name="checkoutDay" title="">
      <option  value="1" >1</option>

       <option  value="2" >2</option>
       <option  value="3" >3</option>
       <option  value="4" >4</option>
       <option  value="5" >5</option>
       <option  value="6" >6</option>
       <option  value="7" >7</option>

       <option  value="8" >8</option>
       <option  value="9" >9</option>
       <option  value="10" >10</option>
       <option  value="11" >11</option>
       <option  value="12" >12</option>
       <option  value="13" >13</option>

       <option  value="14" >14</option>
       <option  value="15" >15</option>
       <option  value="16" >16</option>
       <option  value="17" >17</option>
       <option  value="18"  selected="selected">18</option>
       <option  value="19" >19</option>

       <option  value="20" >20</option>
       <option  value="21" >21</option>
       <option  value="22" >22</option>
       <option  value="23" >23</option>
       <option  value="24" >24</option>
       <option  value="25" >25</option>

       <option  value="26" >26</option>
       <option  value="27" >27</option>
       <option  value="28" >28</option>
       <option  value="29" >29</option>
       <option  value="30" >30</option>
       <option  value="31" >31</option>


     </select>
     <select  class="vbjanh" name="checkoutMonthYear" title="">
      <option  value="092010"  selected="selected">October 2010</option>
       <option  value="102010" >November 2010</option>
       <option  value="112010" >December 2010</option>
       <option  value="002011" >January 2011</option>
       <option  value="012011" >February 2011</option>

       <option  value="022011" >March 2011</option>
       <option  value="032011" >April 2011</option>
       <option  value="042011" >May 2011</option>
       <option  value="052011" >June 2011</option>
       <option  value="062011" >July 2011</option>
       <option  value="072011" >August 2011</option>

       <option  value="082011" >September 2011</option>

     </select>
     <br />
    <br />
    <span class="umoanjg">Adults</span><span class="ifivmjg">Children</span><span class="ngcwmjg">Rooms</span><br />
    <select  class="vbjanh" name="numAdults" title="">
      <option  value="1" >1</option>

       <option  value="2" >2</option>
       <option  value="3" >3</option>
       <option  value="4" >4</option>
       <option  value="5" >5</option>
       <option  value="6" >6</option>
       <option  value="7" >7</option>

       <option  value="8" >8</option>
       <option  value="9" >9</option>
       <option  value="10" >10</option>
       <option  value="11" >11</option>
       <option  value="12" >12</option>
       <option  value="13" >13</option>

       <option  value="14" >14</option>
       <option  value="15" >15</option>
       <option  value="16" >16</option>
       <option  value="17" >17</option>
       <option  value="18" >18</option>
       <option  value="19" >19</option>

       <option  value="20" >20</option>

     </select>
     <select  class="pgrvmh" name="numChildren" title="">
      <option  value="0" >0</option>
       <option  value="1" >1</option>
       <option  value="2" >2</option>
       <option  value="3" >3</option>

       <option  value="4" >4</option>
       <option  value="5" >5</option>
       <option  value="6" >6</option>
       <option  value="7" >7</option>
       <option  value="8" >8</option>
       <option  value="9" >9</option>

       <option  value="10" >10</option>
       <option  value="11" >11</option>
       <option  value="12" >12</option>
       <option  value="13" >13</option>
       <option  value="14" >14</option>
       <option  value="15" >15</option>

       <option  value="16" >16</option>
       <option  value="17" >17</option>
       <option  value="18" >18</option>
       <option  value="19" >19</option>
       <option  value="20" >20</option>

     </select>

     <select  class="duksai" name="numRooms" title="">
      <option  value="1" >1</option>
       <option  value="2" >2</option>
       <option  value="3" >3</option>
       <option  value="4" >4</option>
       <option  value="5" >5</option>

       <option  value="6" >6</option>
       <option  value="7" >7</option>
       <option  value="8" >8</option>
       <option  value="9" >9</option>

     </select>
     <br />
    <br />

    <span class="Label">Sort Results By</span><br />
    <select  class="dropDownValuesText1" name="sortByParam" title="">
      <option  value="BRAND_SORT"  selected="selected">Brand</option>
       <option  value="DISTANCE_SORT" >Distance</option>

     </select>
     <br />
    <br />

    <input  type="hidden" name="fromGeoLocation" value="false"/><input  type="hidden" name="backURL" value="/wireless//6c/us/en/searchForm.action"/><br />
    <span class="luadegf"><input type="image"  name="Find a Hotel" src="http://prodcache.internal.ihg.com/content/dam/mobile/6c/en/us/btn_lrg_find-a-hotel.gif" alt='Find a Hotel'/></span>
   </div>
  </form>
  <table class="onhqbwf">
   <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>

    <td class="gwlmmic">
    <a  href="http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/6c/us/en/coremetric.action?hrefValue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ichotelsgroup.com%2Fh%2Fd%2F6c%2F1%2Fen%2Fhome%3FmobileSite%3Dtrue&amp;linkName=full_html" >
     View Full Website</a>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="/wireless/6c/us/en/truste.action"><img  src="http://prodcache.internal.ihg.com/content/dam/mobile/6c/en/truste_certified_privacy.gif" alt="TRUSTe" width="88" height="25"/></a>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<a  href="/wireless/6c/us/en/terms.action" >
    Terms of Use</a>
    </td>

   </tr>
   <tr>

    <td class="hhsrkom">
    &copy;2001-2010 InterContinental Hotels Group (IHG).<br />All Rights Reserved. IHG Proprietary Information.
    </td>

   </tr>

  </table>
  <span class="fwmduhg"><img src="/wireless/ga.jsp?utmac=MO-1237384-24&amp;utmn=1803370972&amp;utmr=-&amp;utmp=%2Fwireless%2Fjsp%2Fhotel_search.jsp&amp;guid=ON" alt=""/></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is the php which POSTS the form and re-directs to another page. However it doesnt seem to post the data properly. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php 


$FindAHotel  =   (isset($_POST['Find A Hotel'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;

$country  =   (isset($_POST['country'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['country']) : FALSE;
$city   =   (isset($_POST['city'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['city']) : FALSE;
$checkinDay  =   (isset($_POST['checkinDay'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['checkinDay']) : FALSE;
$checkinMonthYear =   (isset($_POST['checkinMonthYear'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['checkinMonthYear']) : FALSE;
$checkoutDay  =   (isset($_POST['checkoutDay'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['checkoutDay']) : FALSE;
$checkoutMonthYear =   (isset($_POST['checkoutMonthYear'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['checkoutMonthYear']) : FALSE;
$numAdults  =   (isset($_POST['numAdults'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['numAdults']) : FALSE;
$numChildren  =   (isset($_POST['numChildren'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['numChildren']) : FALSE;
$numRooms  =   (isset($_POST['numRooms'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['numRooms']) : FALSE;
$sortByParam  =   (isset($_POST['sortByParam'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['sortByParam']) : FALSE;
$fromGeoLocation =   (isset($_POST['fromGeoLocation'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['fromGeoLocation']) : FALSE;
$backURL  =   (isset($_POST['backURL'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['backURL']) : FALSE;


session_start();

if (($_SESSION['optIn']==0)||(!isset($_SESSION['optIn'])))
{

header("Location: http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/ex/us/en/rates.action?mnemonic=SWICC&navigationFlag=true&hotelAvailable=true");
}
else {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script language="JavaScript">
function submitForm(){
document.form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="submitForm()">
<form method="post" action="http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/ex/us/en/search.action" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?php echo($country); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo($city); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="checkinDay" value="<?php echo($checkinDay); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="checkinMonthYear" value="<?php echo($checkinMonthYear); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="checkoutDay" value="<?php echo($checkoutDay); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="checkoutMonthYear" value="<?php echo($checkoutMonthYear); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="numAdults" value="<?php echo($numAdults); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="numChildren" value="<?php echo($numChildren); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="numRooms" value="<?php echo($numRooms); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="sortByParam" value="<?php echo($sortByParam); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="fromGeoLocation" value="<?php echo($fromGeoLocation); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="backURL" value="<?php echo($backURL); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="Find a Hotel" value="<?php echo($FindAHotel); ?>" />

</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>document.myForm.submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
<? }
?>
```

Thanks SO SO much in advanced

Comment: You have a *massive* XSS security problem because you output unescaped user-supplied values to HTML. Please use `htmlspecialchars()` on all your `value="<?php echo ... ?>"` calls, and basically everywhere else you output data to HTML.

Comment: Indeed. Using `striptags()` is **not enough** to protect you, in particular because you're inserting into attribute values, where just a quote character breaks out of context. Drop the `striptags()` at the input stage (it's the Wrong Thing) and use `htmlspecialchars()` at the output stage instead. To cut down on the amount of typing, define a shortcut function `h()` that does `echo htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body onload="submitForm()"
```

will be the problem.

Read about [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), then gather required variables to filter results as narrow as you can. You can find a lot of [cURL-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+curl) here, on Stack Overflow, too.

Comment: Nothing. The problem is your page immediately submitted on load (without user interaction). As i understand you want to submit data to an external site(?). In that case you need cURL.

Comment: Lost me now mate. Possible you could help me out? Obviously will pay! Sorry if that isn't allowed on here!

Comment: Please tell me what do you want to achieve with this form and it's data?

Comment: ok basically the orginal form is at - ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/6c/us/en/searchForm.action - search for swindon and country UK. It then appears with search results. I want to skip this page as these are competitors to the hotel and I just want to go direct to rates page of the express by holiday inn swindon city centre. So I thought by creating a php which sent the data and then re-directed to that page would work. Get me? My email is milesn@gmail.com

Comment: Do you want this page? http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/ex/us/en/hotelDetail.action?mnemonic=SWICC&navigationFlag=true&hotelAvailable=false

Comment: this one mate - http://www.ichotelsgroup.com/wireless/ex/us/en/rates.action?mnemonic=SWICC&navigationFlag=true&searchResultIndex=0      - make sure you do a search for when rooms are available to see it

Comment: btw in the worse case I just want it to show that hotel in the search results

Comment: You can't show only that hotel unless you have control on the server. (No filtering methods to show only that one). Just updated my answer hope it helps.

Comment: Thought so. Sorry wheres your new answer mate?

Answer (score 1):

> What am i doing wrong?

I have no idea :) But here's a few basic debugging steps:

- Look into the form (through the source code or Firebug / Element inspector) to see whether the fields are actually populated
- Do a `print_r($_POST);` in the receiving page to see the raw values that get posted